# change the color of the frame

Tags: beamer, color

I was making slides using WinEdt. I took codes from someone. I want to change the color of the frames appearing in the slides. I tried using different themes but no success. Can anybody help me. Thanks a lot for help. Here is my code. I want to change the color blue to some other color in addition to change of background color.

```
\documentclass[ucs,10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{color}
\date{}
\PassOptionsToClass{t,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false,plainpages=false}}{beamer}
\providecommand\thispdfpagelabel[1]{}
\mode<presentation>
 \usepackage{array}
 \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\usecolortheme{Blue}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=orange}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}
\renewenvironment{definition}{\begin{defi}}{\end{defi}}
\newtheorem{defis}{Definitions}
\renewenvironment{definitions}{\begin{defis}}{\end{defis}}
\newtheorem{facte}{Fait}
\renewenvironment{fact}{\begin{facte}}{\end{facte}}
\newtheorem{coro}{Corollaire}
\renewenvironment{corollary}{\begin{coro}}{\end{coro}}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\renewenvironment{theorem}{\begin{theo}}{\end{theo}}
\newtheorem{Remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{exa}{Example}
\renewenvironment{example}{\begin{exa}}{\end{exa}}
\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\eea}{\end{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\bee}{\begin{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\eee}{\end{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{array}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{array}}
\newcommand{\bi}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\ei}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\bc}{\begin{center}}
\newcommand{\ec}{\end{center}}
\newcommand{\bfr}{\begin{flushright}}
\newcommand{\efr}{\end{flushright}}
\newcommand{\f}{\frac}
\usepackage{rotating}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a minimal example of the code you have? (a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the colours like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=red!70!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=red!60!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=red!50!black}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=gray!50!white}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{test}
        test
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks...its working now. Still I have a doubt. Why it is showing four different layers of red colors on the top of the frame.

Comment: I think, this is because the theme you selected is this way. If you don't want to have different colours, set all the `\setbeamercolor{palette ...}` to the same colour

Comment: This is awesome!!!! Thanks for sharing this